# How to enable square brackets in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I would like it to auto complete so that this:

```
select id from customers
```

becomes this:

```
SELECT [id] FROM [customers]
```

Trying to follow a coding standard, and this would save a lot of needless typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to set native IntelliSense to do this. But you might have luck with some of the 3rd party IntelliSense-like products and/or SQL formatters. I'm not going to list them here simply because this answer will outlast some of them (or at least the URLs I would provide). A search engine should lead you to some free solutions as well as trial editions of various paid solutions.

Comment: Hm, it's unfortunate that intellisense can't be configured the way I would like.  Thanks for the 3rd party suggestions, I will investigate.